# Checking if the object is of same type

Tags: c#, object

Hello I need to know how to check if the object of the same type in C#.

Scenario:

```
class Base_Data{}

class Person : Base_Data { }
class Phone  : Base_data { }

class AnotherClass
{
   public void CheckObject(Base_Data data)
   {
         if (data.Equals(Person.GetType()))
         { //<-- Visual Studio 2010 gives me error, says that I am using 'Person' is a type and not a variable.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO: please reconsider this type of design. Either your method works with `Base_Data` type or it works with the subclasses, `Person` and `Phone`. If there are really different things happening with `CheckObject`, why not just overload the method and have separate `CheckObject(Phone phone)` and `CheckObject(Person person)` methods? It's not a lot more code and you get some compile time checking that the `Base_Data` subclass you are passing to `CheckObject` is supported by `CheckObject`.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You could use the [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is):

```
if (data is Person)
{
    // `data` is an instance of Person
}
```

Another possibility is to use the [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as):

```
var person = data as Person;
if (person != null)
{
    // safely use `person` here
}
```

Or, starting with C# 7, use a [pattern-matching form of the `is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#a-nametype--type-pattern-a) that combines the above two:

```
if (data is Person person)
{
    // `data` is an instance of Person,
    // and you can use it as such through `person`.
}
```

Comment: should an exception be thrown in the second example is false? and if so of what kind?

Comment: @jth41 for that behaviour, simply use the regular cast (`Person person = (Person)data;`) instead of the safe cast.

Comment: Simple yet perfect , thank you.

Answer (score 27):

It depends on exactly what you're after. Using `is` or `as` (as shown in Darin's answer) will tell you if `data` refers to an instance of `Person` *or a subtype*. That's the most common form (although if you can design away from needing it, that would be even better) - and if that's what you need, Darin's answer is the approach to use.

However, if you need an *exact* match - if you don't want to take the particular action if `data` refers to an instance of some class derived from `Person`, only for `Person` itself, you'll need something like this:

```
if (data.GetType() == typeof(Person))
```

This is relatively rare - and it's definitely worth questioning your design at this point.

Comment: Is it possible to implement a class type check in a switch? or is the only way `if`, `else if`?

Comment: @Pierre: As of C# 7, you can use patterns, including type patterns, in switch statements.

Answer (score 11):

Let's fix this one step at a time. The first step is required, the next two are optional but suggested.

The **first correction (which is required)** makes sure that you're not comparing an object of some type with an object of type `System.Type`:

```
if (data.GetType().Equals(typeof(Person))) ...
//      ^^^^^^^^^^
//      add this to make sure you're comparing Type against Type, not
//      Base_Data against Type (which caused the type-check error)!
```

**Second, simplify this** to:

```
if (data is Person) ... // this has (almost) the same meaning as the above;
                        // in your case, it's what you need.
```

**Third, get rid of the `if` statement altogether**! This is done by employing polymorphism (or, more precisely, method overriding) e.g. as follows:

```
class Base_Data
{
    public virtual void Check() { ... }
}

class Person : Base_Data
{
    public override void Check()
    {
        ... // <-- do whatever you would have done inside the if block
    }
}

class AnotherClass
{
    public void CheckData(Base_Data data)
    {
         data.Check();
    }
}
```

As you see, the conditional code has been shifted into a `Check` method of the `Base_Data` class and its derived class `Person`. No more need of such a type-checking `if` statement!

Answer (score 2):

The intention of the question is a bit unclear but I found this question where looking for a way to check if 2 objects are of the same type. Here's my solution for that and some tests that all pass:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class TypeEqualityChecks
{
    class Base_Data { }

    class Person : Base_Data { }
    class Phone  : Base_Data { }

    class AnotherClass
    {
        public static bool CheckObjects(Base_Data d1, Base_Data d2) {
            return d1.GetType() == d2.GetType();
        }
    }
    
    [Test]
    public static void SameTypesAreEqual() {
        Base_Data person1 = new Person();
        Base_Data person2 = new Person();
        Assert.IsTrue(AnotherClass.CheckObjects(person1, person2));
    }
    
    [Test]
    public static void DifferentActualTypesAreNotEqual() {
        Base_Data person = new Person();
        Base_Data phone = new Phone();
        Assert.IsFalse(AnotherClass.CheckObjects(person, phone));
    }
    
    [Test]
    public static void BaseTypeAndChildTypeAreNotEqual() {
        Base_Data baseData = new Base_Data();
        Base_Data person = new Person();
        Assert.IsFalse(AnotherClass.CheckObjects(baseData, person));
    }
}
```