# Check if dynamic object is single value or array in c#

Tags: .net

Which is the best way to check if a dynamic object is an Array or a string/int/etc ?

This is my solution, that works but I'm not sure if the try/cach solution is the best way.

I also tried, to get the `Type` with `.GetType()` method, but that didn't worked.

The `List<object>` should contain simple Datatypes, is castable to an string.

```
private Dictionary<string, List<object>> GetValues(List<dynamic> dynamicList)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<object>> returnDictionary;
    returnDictionary= new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();

    foreach (dynamic item in dynamicList)
    {
        var name = item.Name;
        dynamic value = item.Value;

        try
        {
            string sValue = (string)value;
            returnDictionary.Add(item.Name, new List<object> { sValue });
        }
        catch
        {
            returnDictionary.Add(item.Name, new List<object>((IEnumerable<object>)value));
        }
    }

    return returnDictionary;
}
```

Comment: "but that didn't worked" doesn't tell us anything about what you were seeing. `GetType()` will give you the type, but we don't know what you tried to do or what happened. And if you want a value to be *castable* to string, then you should just populate a `List<string>`...

Comment: You should use reflections in C# ...check if (A is sometype) and than cast it to a that type

Comment: The `List<dynamic>` is part of an deserialzed Json. The `.GetType()` method returns  `Name="JValue" FullName="Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue"`

Comment: I found a solution to check if it's an string or not. `if(value.Type == Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenType.String)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if the object is of same type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287537/checking-if-the-object-is-of-same-type)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'as' keyword.

```
string sValue = value as string;
if(sValue != null) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the is keyword

```
if(value is string)
{
    string StrVal = value as string; 
}
```

Comment: This answer looks correct, but to make it a "high quality answer", you should explain the `is` operator and how it works.